# query on AWS bucket name being global

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

AWS states that bucket names must be unique at the global level.
At the same time buckets are defined at region level.
Does that mean that I can have two buckets with the same name in different regions?

Example : is it possible to create randomn_name.s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com and randomn_name.s3-us-east-2.amazonaws.com under east-1 and east-2 regions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While **data** in Amazon S3 buckets is stored in a Region, **the Bucket Name is globally unique**.

Therefore, you cannot have the same bucket name in different regions.

Answer (score 1):

no, you can't. what you described is the S3 DNS generated for the bucket, and not the bucket name.

the S3 DNS pattern is:

`<bucket-name>.<aws-region>.amazonaws.com`

The first part, `<bucket-name>`, must be unique globally.

You can append the region name in the bucket name, but your S3 DNS will have the region two times.

For example,

S3 bucket name:

- `random_name_us-east-1`

S3 DNS:

- `random_name_us-east-1.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`